# How to load back a dynamically created settingsproperty next time?

Tags: .net, app-config, system.configuration

I created a way to dynamically add `SettingsProperty` to a .NET `app.config` file. It all works nicely, but when I am launching my app the next time I can only see the properties that are created in the designer. How can I load back the properties runtime?

My code for creating the `SettingsProperty` looks like the following:

```
internal void CreateProperty<T>(string propertyName)
{
    string providerName = "LocalFileSettingsProvider";
    System.Configuration.SettingsAttributeDictionary attributes = new SettingsAttributeDictionary();
    System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute attr = new UserScopedSettingAttribute();

    attributes.Add(attr.TypeId, attr);

    System.Configuration.SettingsProperty prop;
    SettingsProvider provider = ApplicationEnvironment.GlobalSettings.Providers[providerName];

    prop = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty(
        propertyName,
        typeof(T),
        provider,
        false,
        default(T),
        System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.String,
        attributes,
        false,
        false
    );

    ApplicationEnvironment.GlobalSettings.Properties.Add(prop);
    ApplicationEnvironment.GlobalSettings.Reload(); 
}
```

When the next run I ask for the settings property I could not find any of the properties created previosuly. No matter if I call the `ApplicationEnvironment.GlobalSettings.Reload();` or not.

Answer (score 1):

User defined configuration settings are tied to the assembly version they were created with. If you have a rolling version number (1.0.*.* for example), You will lose the settings from the last run.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue. IMHO the problem is that the .NET `System.Configuration.SettingsBase` object uses reflection to determine the names, types, etc. of the properties that should be loaded from the persistent storage. And when you add a dynamic settings property, this information is missing. So you'll need to add the settings property definition not only before you *save* the value, but also before you *read* it. In your case, it should be something like this

```
...
// the name and type of the property being read must be known at this point
CreateProperty<T>( propertyName );
ApplicationEnvironment.GlobalSettings.Reload();
T propertyValue = ApplicationEnvironment.GlobalSettings[propertyName];
```

You may want to call the `CreateProperty` method at the beginning for all the properties you want to use and then call `Reload` just once. In both cases, you'll need to know the names and types of the properties.